# Disable automatic trigger build jenkins multibranch

Tags: jenkins

I have a multibranch project in jenkins, and every time I press `Scan Repository Now` it queue a new build just because

```
  ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
Met criteria
```

What I'd like to do is whenever I scan the repository, it only add `Pull Request` to the project without triggering a build. And also, if I turn on scan repository trigger, periodically if not otherwise run, every time it branch indexing, it also build the pull request even after I turn on **Skip initial build on first branch indexing**.

What I'd like to do is whenever there's a comment 'build' in the pull request, then it builds the branch, so if the pr doesn't contain the comment, it should not build anything.

How can I achieve this?

This is my setup

[image: Pull Request]
[image: No Build]

I use `Jenkins 2.180`

Comment: What happens if you remove **Change requests** from **Build strategies**?

Answer (score 2):

According to the pipeline documentation there should be a option do dissable Index Triggers on Multibranch types, see https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options

But i didn't find the option itself either, so i deactivated it per Pipeline definition in the Jenkinsfile of every branch :/

> overrideIndexTriggers
>
> Allows overriding default treatment of branch indexing triggers. If branch indexing triggers are disabled at the multibranch or
>   organization label, options { overrideIndexTriggers(true) } will
>   enable them for this job only. Otherwise, options {
>   overrideIndexTriggers(false) } will disable branch indexing triggers
>   for this job only.

I also use SCM webhooks to autmatically trigger the branch indexing etc

Comment: can you explain how to use SCM webhooks for automatic triggering of branch indexing?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, after some tempering afterwards i realized the branch indexing can't be triggered over SCM webhooks.
Although deleted, new and changed branches will be recognized, it is no full branch indexing.
I then use a time scheduled branch indexing for cleaning up left overs. In example, deleted branches are still listed, but dashed out. After branch indexing they get removed completly

Comment: I was able to trigger branch indexing using Multibranch Scan Trigger plugin. Not sure if it helps you but that resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The default for Build Strategies is to OR the list together. You'll need to  remove the existing build strategies and add an "All Strategies Match" build strategy and add "Change Requests" and "Skip Initial Build on First Branch Indexing" to that.

Source: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58442