# Jenkins skip automatic triggering for job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a project which has multiple jenkins files and a jenkins with the [bitbucket team plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin). The whole point is to separate staging from release. 
When I push on bitbucket a change on a branch that both jobs monitor ( lets say master ) then both jobs will trigger as expected. I would like to disable this trigger on one of the jobs and force it to be manual only (lets say on job A which is the release. The jenkinsfile defined the release process but should be run only manually ) .

so far in the team configuration I cannot stop the trigger but neither in a jenkinsfile I can set a property ( [this#ignorePostCommitHooks](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/triggers/SCMTrigger.java) )  and make it work. ( I do setup it. But it does nothing ). Is there a way to configure the job triggering?

Also a side question, Jenkins offers this option[image: skip initial build on first branch indexing]

But even after setting it when I save the configurations and jenkins starts looking in the repository for matching projects / branches it will start building any branch it finds. Is there a way for this option to actually work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56593931/disable-automatic-trigger-build-jenkins-multibranch/60566271#60566271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping it into an all match make it work.

[image: worked]